# Foward data from Logo Siemens 8 to Web page

Tags: plc

I'm looking for a way to transfer data from my logo plc to my webpage, does anyone know a way to do it? 
For example, I would like to know if my logo it's turned on or not.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To transfer PLC data to your webpage access the Logo's built in webserver.  Your webpage could display the Logo's running status in a frame, or whatever methods suits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the input output network function from the built in library of the logo plc.Furthermore you can use the VM mapping function to send or receive signals .

Comment: A bit old but can you write an example in html about get an analog input or a value from VM please?